# Is deanonymisation via propagation analysis possible for Monero?

Tags: privacy, network, bitcoin

In Bitcoin, every node tries to establish 8 outgoing connections and sends new messages to its neighbors with random delays ("diffusion"). This enables certain deanonymisation attacks, where an attacker establishes many parallel connections to many nodes and creates an approximate (tx -> IP) mapping based on network propagation delays, e.g. as described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7418) (another propagation algorithm was used at the time, but the improvement was only marginal, as per [another paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08761)).

If I understand correctly, Kovri aims to solve this problem for Monero, but is not yet deployed. Does this mean that correlation of Monero transactions based on traffic analysis is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same idea applies to Monero, as it uses a very similar network system.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is there any research on the subject?

Comment: Not that I know of for Monero, but I expect most Bitcoin research will generally apply to Monero here.